# Парсинг Twitter в python

Tags: python

Есть задача спарсить имена фолловеров определенного аккаунта твиттер. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для этого? Пробовал парсить с помощью selenium, но это слишком медленно работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) для парсинга твиттера или [tweet-parser](https://pypi.org/project/tweet-parser/). Вот пример гайда: [тык](https://towardsdatascience.com/extracting-twitter-data-pre-processing-and-sentiment-analysis-using-python-3-0-7192bd8b47cf). Уверен, что у твиттера есть еще [api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs) для доступа к таким данным (по аналогии с вк), а для работы с ним нужен только requests модуль и json

Comment: Api есть, но я не могу им воспользоваться. Перехожу на https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps, создаю приложение и ничего не выходит

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-twitter-api-with-python/ Тут используется RapidAPI для манипуляций с твиттером. Попробуйте и этот вариант.

Comment: Все равно же нужен Twitter api

Comment: Помоги пожалуйста, это срочно

Comment: Без твиттер api ничего не будет работать, естественно. Что конкретно у тебя не работает, после создания приложения?

Comment: вот https://prnt.sc/sgoxcg

Comment: Так все же понятно: твой запрос на доступ к апи на рассмотрении, а из-за COVID19 может еще и затянуться, до этого момента у тебя нет возможности получить какие-либо данные твиттера не используя скрапперы различного рода (Selenium, Scrapy, request-html и другие)

Comment: Пробуй другие варианты, кроме selenium (указаны в скобках выше), если это срочно, если нет, то жди сообщения на почте

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: еще вопрос. Как отфильтровать список так, чтобы в нем остались только те элементы, которые начинаются с "@". Пример списка: list = ["@mari1977", "просто текст", "Follow", "@ickWil59543298"]

Comment: Модуль регулярных выражений re, в помощь

Comment: или еще можно перебрать все значения массива и те, в которых есть @ в новый список загонять. Вот пример с генератором: users = [user for user in data if '@' in user]